# Remove an attribute but change its element name to that attribute's value using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a need to change an XML document to another format using XSLT.  I have tried a number of examples I've come across but so far I have not succeeded as I am not an XSLT guru.  My source always contains a ***Value*** element and an attribute called ***AttributeID*** that needs to replace the element name of ***Value***.

My source is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<STEP-ProductInformation ContextID="Context1" WorkspaceID="Main">
   <Entities>
      <Entity UserTypeID="Target" ParentID="Target_Category">
         <Name>p53 (Thr155) phosphate</Name>
         <Values>
           <Value AttributeID="XXXXXXX">T15010</Value>
           <Value AttributeID="YYYYYYYYYYY">ENSG00000141510</Value>
           <Value AttributeID="ZZZZZZZZZZZZ" ID="NA">NA</Value>
...
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<STEP-ProductInformation ContextID="Context1" WorkspaceID="Main">
   <Entities>
      <Entity UserTypeID="Target" ParentID="Target_Category">
         <Name>p53 (Thr155) phosphate</Name>
         <Values>
           <XXXXXXX>T15010</XXXXXXX>
           <YYYYYYYYYYY>ENSG00000141510</YYYYYYYYYYY>
           <ZZZZZZZZZZZZ ID="NA">NA</ZZZZZZZZZZZZ>
...
```

My Last XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="Value">
      <xsl:element name="{@AttributeID}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which did not produce what I wanted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<STEP-ProductInformation ContextID="Context1" WorkspaceID="Main">
   <Entities>
      <Entity UserTypeID="Target" ParentID="Target_Category">
         <Name>p53 (Thr155) phosphate</Name>
         <Values>
            <Value AttributeID="XXXXXXX">T15010</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="YYYYYYYYYYY">ENSG00000141510</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="ZZZZZZZZZZZZ" ID="NA">NA</Value>
...
```

I am clearly missing something.

Entire Source Sample:

```
<STEP-ProductInformation ContextID="Context1" WorkspaceID="Main">
 <Entities>
  <Entity UserTypeID="Target" ParentID="Target_Category">
     <Name>p53 (Thr155) phosphate</Name>
     <Values>
        <Value AttributeID="TARGETNO">T15010</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="ACCESSION_ENSGENE">ENSG00000141510</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="WHOLEPROTEINFLAG_YNNA" ID="NA">NA</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="ALTNAMES">Antigen NY-CO-13,Cellular tumor antigen p53,FLJ92943,LFS1,P53,Phosphoprotein p53,TP53,TRP53,Tumor suppressor p53,p53 antigen,p53 transformation suppressor,p53 tumor suppressor,transformation-related protein 53,tumor protein p53</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="PNAME">p53</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="TARGETNAME">p53 (Thr155) phosphate</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="MW">43653.17774</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="ASSENSIONID">P04637</Value>
        <MultiValue AttributeID="TARGET_KEYWORDS">
           <Value>pp53</Value>
           <Value>p-p53</Value>
        </MultiValue>
        <Value AttributeID="SORTTERM">P53</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="ACCESSION_GP">NP_000537</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="GNAMES">TP53</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="PROTEIN_GROUP_NAME">p53</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="UNIPROT">P04637</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="PROTEIN_GROUP_DESCR">a transcription factor and major tumor suppressor.</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="ACCESSION_GENE">7157</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="ORGANISM_COMMON_NAME">human</Value>
        <MultiValue AttributeID="DEVSECTIONS">
           <Value>Cell Biology</Value>
        </MultiValue>
        <Value AttributeID="TARGETTYPE">Protein</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="TSCOMPOSITESCORE">359.25922</Value>
        <MultiValue AttributeID="DEVSUBSECTIONS">
           <Value>DNA Damage</Value>
        </MultiValue>
        <MultiValue AttributeID="TARGET_DISEASES">
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Basal cell carcinoma</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Bladder cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Chronic myeloid leukemia</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Colorectal cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Endometrial cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Glioma</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Melanoma</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Non-small cell lung cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Pancreatic cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Pathways in cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Prostate cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Small cell lung cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Thyroid cancer</Value>
           <Value>Neurodegenerative Diseases &gt; Amyotrophic lateral sclerosis (ALS)</Value>
           <Value>Neurodegenerative Diseases &gt; Huntington&apos;s disease</Value>
        </MultiValue>
        <MultiValue AttributeID="TARGET_PATHWAYS">
           <Value>Crosstalk between PTMs</Value>
           <Value>Warburg Effect</Value>
           <Value>SAPK/JNK Signaling Cascades</Value>
           <Value>Protein Acetylation</Value>
           <Value>Regulation of P38 MAPKs</Value>
           <Value>ErbB/HER Signaling</Value>
           <Value>G2/M DNA Damage Checkpoint</Value>
           <Value>G1/S Checkpoint</Value>
           <Value>Apoptosis Regulation</Value>
           <Value>Mitochondrial Control of Apoptosis</Value>
           <Value>AMPK Signaling</Value>
           <Value>PI3K/Akt Signaling</Value>
        </MultiValue>
        <MultiValue AttributeID="TARGET_RESEARCHAREAS">
           <Value>Neurobiology &gt; Overview</Value>
           <Value>Immunology &gt; Overview</Value>
           <Value>Development &gt; Wnt Signaling</Value>
           <Value>Neurobiology &gt; Neurodegenerative Disorders</Value>
           <Value>Growth and Viability &gt; MAPK Signaling</Value>
           <Value>Growth and Viability &gt; DNA Damage and Repair</Value>
           <Value>Growth and Viability &gt; Apoptosis/Necrosis/Autophagy</Value>
           <Value>Growth and Viability &gt; Cell Cycle and Checkpoint Control</Value>
        </MultiValue>
        <Value AttributeID="ACCESSION_ENSP">ENSP00000269305</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="MODIFICATION">phosphate</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="PRIMARYDEVSECTION">Cell Biology</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="PRIMARYDEVSUBSECTION">DNA Damage</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="PROTORG_SEQUENCE">MEEPQSDPSVEPPLSQETFSDLWKLLPENNVLSPLPSQAMDDLMLSPDDIEQWFTEDPGPDEAPRMPEAAPPVAPAPAAPTPAAPAPAPSWPLSSSVPSQKTYQGSYGFRLGFLHSGTAKSVTCTYSPALNKMFCQLAKTCPVQLWVDSTPPPGTRVRAMAIYKQSQHMTEVVRRCPHHERCSDSDGLAPPQHLIRVEGNLRVEYLDDRNTFRHSVVVPYEPPEVGSDCTTIHYNYMCNSSCMGGMNRRPILTIITLEDSSGNLLGRNSFEVRVCACPGRDRRTEEENLRKKGEPHHELPPGSTKRALPNNTSSSPQPKKKPLDGEYFTLQIRGRERFEMFRELNEALELKDAQAGKEPGGSRAHSSHLKSKKGQSTSRHKKLMFKTEGPDSD</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="SITE">Thr155</Value>
        <MultiValue AttributeID="PROTEIN_KEYWORDS">
           <Value>TP53</Value>
        </MultiValue>
     </Values>
  </Entity>
 </Entities>
</STEP-ProductInformation>
```

Expected Results:

```
<STEP-ProductInformation ContextID="Context1" WorkspaceID="Main">
 <Entities>
  <Entity UserTypeID="Target" ParentID="Target_Category">
     <Name>p53 (Thr155) phosphate</Name>
     <Values>
        <TARGETNO>T15010</TARGETNO>
        <ACCESSION_ENSGENE>ENSG00000141510</ACCESSION_ENSGENE>
        <WHOLEPROTEINFLAG_YNNA ID="NA">NA</WHOLEPROTEINFLAG_YNNA>
        <ALTNAMES>Antigen NY-CO-13,Cellular tumor antigen p53,FLJ92943,LFS1,P53,Phosphoprotein p53,TP53,TRP53,Tumor suppressor p53,p53 antigen,p53 transformation suppressor,p53 tumor suppressor,transformation-related protein 53,tumor protein p53</ALTNAMES>
        <PNAME>p53</PNAME>
        <TARGETNAME>p53 (Thr155) phosphate</TARGETNAME>
        <MW>43653.17774</MW>
        <ASSENSIONID>P04637</ASSENSIONID>
        <TARGET_KEYWORDS>
           <Value>pp53</Value>
           <Value>p-p53</Value>
        </TARGET_KEYWORDS>
        <SORTTERM>P53</SORTTERM>
        <ACCESSION_GP>NP_000537</ACCESSION_GP>
        <GNAMES>TP53</GNAMES>
        <PROTEIN_GROUP_NAME>p53</PROTEIN_GROUP_NAME>
        <UNIPROT>P04637</UNIPROT>
        <PROTEIN_GROUP_DESCR>a transcription factor and major tumor suppressor.</PROTEIN_GROUP_DESCR>
        <ACCESSION_GENE>7157</ACCESSION_GENE>
        <ORGANISM_COMMON_NAME>human</ORGANISM_COMMON_NAME>
        <DEVSECTIONS>
           <Value>Cell Biology</Value>
        </DEVSECTIONS>
        <TARGETTYPE>Protein</TARGETTYPE>
        <TSCOMPOSITESCORE>359.25922</TSCOMPOSITESCORE>
        <DEVSUBSECTIONS>
           <Value>DNA Damage</Value>
        </DEVSUBSECTIONS>
        <TARGET_DISEASES>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Basal cell carcinoma</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Bladder cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Chronic myeloid leukemia</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Colorectal cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Endometrial cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Glioma</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Melanoma</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Non-small cell lung cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Pancreatic cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Pathways in cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Prostate cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Small cell lung cancer</Value>
           <Value>Cancer &gt; Thyroid cancer</Value>
           <Value>Neurodegenerative Diseases &gt; Amyotrophic lateral sclerosis (ALS)</Value>
           <Value>Neurodegenerative Diseases &gt; Huntington&apos;s disease</Value>
        </TARGET_DISEASES>
        <TARGET_PATHWAYS>
           <Value>Crosstalk between PTMs</Value>
           <Value>Warburg Effect</Value>
           <Value>SAPK/JNK Signaling Cascades</Value>
           <Value>Protein Acetylation</Value>
           <Value>Regulation of P38 MAPKs</Value>
           <Value>ErbB/HER Signaling</Value>
           <Value>G2/M DNA Damage Checkpoint</Value>
           <Value>G1/S Checkpoint</Value>
           <Value>Apoptosis Regulation</Value>
           <Value>Mitochondrial Control of Apoptosis</Value>
           <Value>AMPK Signaling</Value>
           <Value>PI3K/Akt Signaling</Value>
        </TARGET_PATHWAYS>
        <TARGET_RESEARCHAREAS>
           <Value>Neurobiology &gt; Overview</Value>
           <Value>Immunology &gt; Overview</Value>
           <Value>Development &gt; Wnt Signaling</Value>
           <Value>Neurobiology &gt; Neurodegenerative Disorders</Value>
           <Value>Growth and Viability &gt; MAPK Signaling</Value>
           <Value>Growth and Viability &gt; DNA Damage and Repair</Value>
           <Value>Growth and Viability &gt; Apoptosis/Necrosis/Autophagy</Value>
           <Value>Growth and Viability &gt; Cell Cycle and Checkpoint Control</Value>
        </TARGET_RESEARCHAREAS>
        <ACCESSION_ENSP>ENSP00000269305</ACCESSION_ENSP>
        <MODIFICATION>phosphate</MODIFICATION>
        <PRIMARYDEVSECTION>Cell Biology</PRIMARYDEVSECTION>
        <PRIMARYDEVSUBSECTION>DNA Damage</PRIMARYDEVSUBSECTION>
        <PROTORG_SEQUENCE>MEEPQSDPSVEPPLSQETFSDLWKLLPENNVLSPLPSQAMDDLMLSPDDIEQWFTEDPGPDEAPRMPEAAPPVAPAPAAPTPAAPAPAPSWPLSSSVPSQKTYQGSYGFRLGFLHSGTAKSVTCTYSPALNKMFCQLAKTCPVQLWVDSTPPPGTRVRAMAIYKQSQHMTEVVRRCPHHERCSDSDGLAPPQHLIRVEGNLRVEYLDDRNTFRHSVVVPYEPPEVGSDCTTIHYNYMCNSSCMGGMNRRPILTIITLEDSSGNLLGRNSFEVRVCACPGRDRRTEEENLRKKGEPHHELPPGSTKRALPNNTSSSPQPKKKPLDGEYFTLQIRGRERFEMFRELNEALELKDAQAGKEPGGSRAHSSHLKSKKGQSTSRHKKLMFKTEGPDSD</PROTORG_SEQUENCE>
        <SITE>Thr155</SITE>
        <PROTEIN_KEYWORDS>
           <Value>TP53</Value>
        </PROTEIN_KEYWORDS>
     </Values>
  </Entity>
 </Entities>
</STEP-ProductInformation>
```

Comment: "I have tried a number of examples I've come across but so far I have not succeeded as I am not an XSLT guru." Is that the best learning strategy? Examples always need to be adapted, and you can't do that unless you understand them, and to understand them, you need to do some reading.

Comment: Please provide **complete** examples, including the closing tags.

Comment: Complete example added.  As M. Kay notes, I have read and continue to do so but this is a stretch for me so thank you in advance.

Comment: You also need to post the expected output of the extended input example. Clearly, the rule of replacing the name of a `Value` element cannot be applied when there is no `AttributeID` attribute. OTOH, you have some `MultiValue` elements with an `AttributeID` attribute, and it's not clear whether they should be changed or not.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  I have posted the expected results.  I had to go back to the requestor and the `MultiValue` elements are to be changed as well if there is an `AttributeID` attribute and the answer was yes.  The expected results reflect this.

Comment: Why is `<MultiValue AttributeID="DEVSECTIONS">` treated differently from `<MultiValue AttributeID="DEVSUBSECTIONS">`?

Comment: That was an editing error on my part.  It should be handled the same as the other MultiValue elements.  Thanks again for your help in understanding this @michael.hor257k

Comment: @sawmkw Isn't your question answered then?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I had made an editing error on the expected results which I manually generated.  I still cannot get the XSLT to transform the source using an on-line editor.  It gives me `Invalid element name (empty sequence)` although the source looks fine to me...

Comment: @sawmkw You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/a9GiwY (when the site is not down, which it often is these days).

Comment: Thanks so much @michael.hor257k, without your help I could not have gotten this done.  I wished I had seen your solution before I got mine working as yours is more elegant.

Comment: @sawmkw Your solution is almost identical to mine, except you have the same template twice.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. I have rolled back your edit. You can see this in your [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45002617/revisions). This is to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a template to traverse the tree from root element, `<Values>`. Also use `text()` since you are in the current node whereas `*` looks for children of current node and so returns nothing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Values">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Value"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Value">
      <xsl:element name="{@AttributeID}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*[name()!='AttributeID']"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This does not produce the expected output: the `ID` attribute is missing.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - thanks for pointing that out. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get the expected result:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Values">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Value">
            <xsl:element name="{@AttributeID}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='AttributeID')]"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's another:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Value">
    <xsl:element name="{@AttributeID}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@AttributeID"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that both assume that `AttributeID` contains a valid XML element name.

---

### Added in response to changed requirements:

I am guessing you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Value[@AttributeID] | MultiValue[@AttributeID]">
    <xsl:element name="{@AttributeID}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@AttributeID"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried both of these be neither worked.  But this may be to my leaving out some of the source elements.  I have updated my original post and thank you for your help.

Comment: @sawmkw You are wrong: the 2nd stylesheet does provide the expected result with your updated input.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I am clearly doing something else incorrectly.  Thank you for your help.